# Does CUDA's thrust::inclusive_scan() have an 'init' parameter?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

According to CUDA's [Thrust library documentation](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html#ga7109170b96a48fab736e52b75f423464), `thrust::inclusive_scan()` has **4** parameters:

```
OutputIterator thrust::inclusive_scan(InputIterator       first,
                                      InputIterator       last,
                                      OutputIterator      result,
                                      AssociativeOperator binary_op 
                                     )
```

Yet in the usage demonstration (in the same documentation), they pass **5** parameters. An extra 4th parameter is passed as an intial value for the scan (exactly like in [`thrust::exclusive_scan()`](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html#gaa3f981950f16c9dae693590b79a9ff90)):

```
int data[10] = {-5, 0, 2, -3, 2, 4, 0, -1, 2, 8};
thrust::maximum<int> binary_op;
thrust::inclusive_scan(data, data + 10, data, 1, binary_op); // in-place scan
```

Now, my code will only compile passing 4 parameters (passing 5 gives error `no instance of overloaded function "thrust::inclusive_scan" matches the argument list`), but I happen to need to initialise my rolling maximum just like in the example.

Can anyone clarify how to initialise the inclusive scan?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this usage demonstration?

Comment: In the Thrust library documentation: http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__prefixsums.html#ga7109170b96a48fab736e52b75f423464

Comment: Ha, unless I'm not getting something, that seems plain wrong. Perhaps report it.

Comment: Sure, but I *need* the demonstration to be right! Otherwise how do I initialise my rolling maximum? More generally, how does Nvidia expect you perform a *binary* operation at the start of the inclusive scan (i.e. using only the first element of the array) without some other initial value!?

Comment: try to add the init value to each element of the result vector after  the inclusive scan

Comment: element 1 in `result` = element 1 in `input` for the inclusive scan

Comment: Ahh many thanks. I'll mark it answered if you post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've reported the documentation error now anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't understand what the inclusive scan operation is. There is no such thing as initialising an inclusive scan. By definition, the first value of an inclusive scan is always the first element of the sequence.

So for the sequence

```
 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

the inclusive scan is

```
[ 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28 ]
```

and the exclusive scan (initialised to zero) is

```
[ 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21 ]
```

Comment: Yes, I see. I suppose I got confused by the erroneous usage demonstration in the Thrust library documentation. Thanks.